# Как скрыть кнопку меню, находясь на странице этой кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте! Возник такой вопрос. Имеется меню, например "Тарифы, отзывы, отправить заявку, о нас". Каким образом можно скрыть кнопку меню той страницы,на которой находится сейчас пользователь и показывать другую? Например если пользователь находится на странице "Тарифы", то не показывать кнопку тарифы, а показывать например "Спец. предложения"?

Comment: Какой вид имеют url'ы?(ЧПУ ли нет?) Покажите ваш html этих кнопок.

Comment: Кнопки сделаны оригинальным способом) Это картинка с ссылкой на страницу

Comment: Можно сравнить url и ссылку в кнопке с помощью скрипта, если совпали добавить класс или стиль css который спрячет ее.
Если сайт динамический, то в шаблоне сравнить id страницы и кнопки ссылкой, если совпадают, то прятать или не выводить ее.

Comment: а что это за скрипт?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого отлично подойдет PHP. Вот код для примера:

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "restoration")){
echo <<<HTML
<li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Отправить заявку</a></li>
<li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
HTML;
}
else{
echo <<<HTML
<li><a href="#">Тарифы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Отправить заявку</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
HTML;}
?>
```

В этом случае, например, если адрес страницы содержит слово `restoration`, то будет выведено меню с 3 ссылками, в остальных случаях выведутся 4 ссылки.

Или так:

```
<?php $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($currentpage=="/index.php"){
$displaynone = "style=\"display:none\"";}
?>

<li <?php echo $displaynone;?>><a href="#">Тарифы</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Отправить заявку</a></li>
<li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
```

В этом случае, если адрес будет index.php, то в первую ссылку добавится стиль `display:none`.

Кроме этого есть несколько других вариантов. Вы также можете комбинировать данные варианты между собой.

Answer (score 1):

Если с помощью js, то вот так можно:

```js
$(function() {
  var page = location.href.replace(/https?\:\/{2}.+\..+(\/.+)/, '$1');
  if(page == '/js') $('#a').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a">JS</div>
<div id="b">Главная</div>
<div id="c">О нас</div>
<div id="d">Новости</div>
<div id="e">Контакты</div>
```

Comment: т.е. такое условие if(page == '/js') $('#a').css('display', 'none'); нужно прописать для каждой ссылки? Прошу прощение, если вопрос глупый,я во всем этом очень сильно новичок (

Comment: @Alla, да. Ну вообще для таких целей это делается в `PHP`. Но если вам нужно в `JS`, то вот так